# Number of categorical points in percentage within a polygon(s)

Tags: arcgis-pro, spatial-statistics

I have a point layer which has `categorical values` from `1-10`, I would like to find the number of points both in count and percentage for each categorical value within a `polygon` (multipart polygons).

What tool can I use in `ArcGIS Pro 3.03` to find these percentages and count and show them spatially as a classification?

Update:

I did try the `Aggregate Points` tool but that returns the count of points in general not with respect to each categorical value.

Answer (score 1):

The `summarize within` tool does the job as it creates a `summary table` with the columns I want i.e. `Count` and `Percent`. I can then join to the point layer to show the results spatially.

- Just make sure not to select anything under `summary fields` and
  leave it empty.
- Under group field select the column that has the categorical values.

[image]